# Is frost at the far edges of my attic a concern?

Tags: attic, inspection, ice

(I am a first time homeowner doing my first attic inspection.)

The prolonged cold weather in my area gave me a good opportunity to look for problems in my attic yesterday.  The only thing I found that I was unsure about was some frost on the underside of the roof.  It's not very heavy frost, and it is confined to the far edges of the attic.

Is this a cause for concern?

Comment: We need pictures or some heavy detail.  What are the dimensions of the frost?

Comment: And is there insulation below the frosted areas? And is there a vapor barrier anywhere?

Comment: Having frost inside the attic is not good. It means water has penetrated below the roof. It may be due to faulty shingling or lack of a drip edge. It should be addressed to prevent rotting of the boards at the edge of the roof.

Comment: @DMoore - Unfortunately, I didn't think to take photos, but there are a couple of patches maybe about 6ft x 4ft, although the rafters in that space do not have frost.

Comment: @bib - There is insulation below that area, with the lowest layer having a vapor barrier that faces downward.

Comment: @getterdun - I just wanted to clarify that this is frost, not ice.  Is it still a concern?